# Canvas layout and widget lingering with maxWidth/maxHeight

Tags: qooxdoo

In [this example](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/4.1/demobrowser/#layout~Canvas_MinMaxSizes.html), the green block has equal `top` and `bottom` layout properties. When the browser window gets resized, the block lingers to the top; that means, top offset remains constant, while bottom offset varies according to `maxHeight` widget property. (The block would also linger to the left should `left` layout property and `maxWidth` widget property be set.)

How do I reverse the behavior, so that the widget lingers to the bottom/right corner?

Answer (score 0):

- Add a composite as the root widget, give it a grid layout
- add the widget you want to position fixed to the lower left corner of the screen to the composite, with row 1 and column 1
- set the flex of row 0 and column 0 to 1
- set a fixed height/width for rows 1 and 2 and columns 1 and 2

Width of column 1 and height of row 1 should be the dimensions you want for your widget.

Alternatively, you can play with row/column min/max height/width - see [the grid layout API](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/#qx.ui.layout.Grid) for all possibilities.

Yet another alternative is to use a canvas layout, where widgets stay where you put them, and their position or size is never recalculated automatically, and add a listener to the resize event of the container, in which you manually recompute everything. However, I never found a situation in which qooxdoo's containers and layouts didn't allow me to avoid this.

The demo you link to is a demo for what its name says - minimum and maximum sizes of widgets, not positioning. Controlling positioning in qooxdoo happens via layouts. (To some extent, layouts can also be used to specify rules for sizing, though.)